# Disable or hide an entry field in the CMS

Tags: field

Is there a way to hide or disable an entry field in the CMS so that the field still exists in the database but can not be edited by a user. The field will only ever be altered dynamically from a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [inject some CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) to hide it specifically.

Comment: yeah I know we can use css just wondered if there was a better way to do it with the backend?

Comment: No, not at the moment

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a plugin called [Incognito Field](https://github.com/mmikkel/IncognitoField-Craft), which is basically a plain ol' PlainText field that can be set to `disabled`, `readonly` or `hidden`. Perfect when you need to update a field via a plugin and never via the Control Panel.

Comment: Nice! Bookmarked for future use. This would have been perfect on a project we did awhile back.